# A question from the proof of the diameter of curve complex is infinite (Luo's proof)

Tags: surfaces, geometric-topology, geometric-group-theory

In [Masur and Minsky's paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9804098.pdf), p.14, Proposition 3.6 Luo's proof, it says "but $\gamma_n\to \mu$ and $\mu$ maximal implies $\beta_n \to \mu$", which I feel confused: when $\gamma_n\to \mu$ and $\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ are disjoint, I think $\gamma_n$ doesn't necessarily bring $\beta_n$ to converge to $\mu$. Even, thinking intuitively, it seems possible for $\beta_n$ to be farther from $\mu$ as $n$ gets larger. I don't see how combined with $\mu$ maximal would force $\gamma_n$ to make $\beta_n$ converge to $\mu$ as $\gamma_n$ converges to $\mu$.

Notations: $\mu$ is a maximal geodesic lamination and
let $\gamma_i$ be any sequence of closed geodesics converging geometrically to $\mu$. For each $\gamma_n$ we may then find $\beta_n$ with $d(\beta_n, \gamma_n) = 1$ and $d(\gamma_0, \beta_n) = N-1$.

Comment: What do you think intuitively happens with $\beta_n$?

Comment: @PaulPlummer Intuitively, I think it can be random. Since $d(\beta_n,\gamma_n)=1$ only means $\beta_n,\gamma_n$ are disjoint, I can't see $\gamma_i\to \mu$ would bring $\beta_i$ to converge to $\mu$.

Comment: Do you think $\beta_n$ can converge at all(to any lamination)?

Comment: @PaulPlummer Honestly, I have no idea. Maybe$\mu$ being maximal would make $\beta_n$ converge? But I can't see why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you should be thinking about $\mu$ as the stable lamination coming from a pseudo-Anosov. To help a bit more with the intuition, you should think about $\gamma_n$ as a very long curves on the surface "going all over", and longer and more "all over" as $n$ increases(the sequence of curves is not contained on any subsurface). This will mean $\beta_n$ will have to follow $\gamma_n$ for a long time (so will look like $\gamma_n$, which is why we get this convergence) to be disjoint. At least that is the basic intuition you should have/develop.

Say $\beta_n \to \beta$(maybe passing to subsequence). By disjointness of $\beta_n$ and $\gamma_n$ we get $\beta$ is "disjoint" from $\mu$, so $\beta \cup \mu$ is a lamination. With the assumption that $\mu$ is maximal we get $\beta$ must be a sublamination. The unstated jump in the sketch is that $\mu$ is minimal in the sense that any leaf in the lamination is dense in the lamination(this happens in the pA case). With that you get that $\beta = \mu$. From here you can continue the proof.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think $\mu$ being maximal also rules out the case that $\mu$ and $\gamma_n$ stay in a subsurface while $\{\beta_n\}$ stays in a subsurface which is disjoint from the former subsurface, right?

Comment: @Katherine Basically yes. If there was a subsurface that $\mu$ stayed in a proper subsurface you could add to the lamination, so it wasn't maximal

Comment: Thanks! One thing I am a little confused about is why $\beta$ is also dense in the lamination. (I think you mean, since $\beta$ is also dense in the lamination and $\mu$ is minimal in that sense, we get $\beta=\mu$.)

Comment: @Katherine $\beta$, which is a sublamination, contains a leaf from $\mu$ so is dense in $\mu$